# Javascript in PHP file which outputs JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Is there a way to use `Javascript` code inside a `PHP` file that uses `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to output in `JSON` format?

EDIT: I'm trying to change the color of a css class when `$est = 'Crest'`but I get the `javascript` code printed along. `Javascript` part is inside comment `/*HERE*/`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$vs=array();
$vs1=array();

include("json/connectorcl.php");

if ((isset ($_GET['ty'])) and (isset ($_GET['est']))){
    $nprocesso = $_GET['ty'];
    $est =  $_GET['est'];


if ($est == 'Crest') {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM PATERN WHERE CREST='1'";
$result2 = oci_parse($connect, $query2);
oci_execute($result2);

/*HERE*/
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.time-title').css({'color':'blue'});</script>";
/*HERE*/
}
ELSE  {
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM PATERN";
$result2 = oci_parse($connect, $query2);
oci_execute($result2);
}

while($res2 = oci_fetch_array($result2) AND $res5 = oci_fetch_array($result5))  {
 $a++;   
 $vs['id']= $a;
 $vs['title']='VS - '.$res2['CATEGORIA_DESC'];
 $vs['startdate']=$res2['DATAMSG'];
 $vs['enddate']=$res2['DATAMSG'];
 $vs['description']= '1ºH - '.$res2['VALOR'].'| MAX - '.$res5['MAXVAL'].'| MIN - '.$res5['MINVAL'].'| AVG - '.$res5['AVGVAL'];
 $vs['date_display']='ho';
 $vs['icon']='plus_blue.png';
 $vs['importance']='30';

 $b=$a;
 array_push($vs1,$vs);
}

echo str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($vs1), ENT_NOQUOTES));}}
```

Comment: Please share with us the code that you're using.

Comment: Could you show us the code you want to use?

Comment: Well repair you error within javascript.

Comment: Just updated question. Hope makes it more understandable.

Comment: If you try to echo out javascript, then you will not have valid JSON. Also, you shouldn't be stripped out array indicators in teh JSON, you are going to make invalid JSON by doing so.  Finally, you should not be HTML-encoding the JSON after it is formed, again you are going to make invalid JSON.  You can HTML-encode your data on the client side.  Your JSON feed should give only JSON data, not try to format for display as well.  You are having a fundamental problem in trying to mix your data feed with display concerns and are going to end up with a mess.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you question right, yes you can.

Example, json.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('text' => 'im json baby'));
```

Comment: That is not what I'm trying to do. I want to use a javascript script inside a PHP file that outputs in json format.

Comment: javascript is run on the client while the php file is run on the server, which returns html if you choose to, but first after its executed. I'm afraid you have to narrow down your problem and be more specific about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array('text' => CONTENT_TO_BE_FETCHED));

But if you want to change the color of the css, try something like this :

$vs['css']= 'blue';